# icomoon font on iOS 8 do no work anymore

Tags: ios8, custom-font

I am using icomoon font in my app, it works very well. 
This way we removed all our png icons and save disk space, but on iOS 8 beta 3, all my icons do not appear.

It seems that there is a problem in the generated font by icomoon since this is OK using http://fontello.com.

Did you experienced this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Thierry